# ¿Porque no funciona el código dentro del evento de Jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        });
                $(function() {
                        $( "#abrir" ).on( "click", function() {


                            function toggleVisibility() {
                            $('.ic3').toggleclass('hidden');
                            $('.ic4').toggleclass('hidden');
                            $('.ic5').toggleclass('hidden');
                            $('.ic6').toggleclass('hidden');
                            $('.ic7').toggleclass('hidden');
                            }
                        });
                    });
```

Comment: Te da algún error? o algo que te haga pensar que esta mal?

Comment: hola a darle click al boton no me oculta las clases que quiero ocultar en este caso  ic3 ic4 ic5 ic6 ic7

Comment: Tu clase hidden si tiene un display:none o algún código css para ocultar

Comment: no le ha metido aun nada de css donde iria y como?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando tienes un click handler en jQuery, no necesitas llamar a otra funcion con `onclick`.  Simplemente seria asi:

```js
 $(function() {
     $( "#abrir" ).on( "click", function() {
                            
           $('.ic3').toggleClass('hidden');
           $('.ic4').toggleClass('hidden');
           $('.ic5').toggleClass('hidden');
           $('.ic6').toggleClass('hidden');
           $('.ic7').toggleClass('hidden');
                           
     });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="abrir">Click me</button>
<div class="ic3">Uno</div>
<div class="ic4">Dos</div>
<div class="ic5">Tres</div>
<div class="ic6">Cuatro</div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias alanfcm me ha servido pero ahora tengo un problema el boton esta a lado derecho y cuando le doy a ocultar el boton se va hacia la derecha y queda pegado al ic1 ic2 y quiero que esa infomacion y el boton queden en linea.gracias seria buena ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que has declarado una funcion, pero esta funcion sigue sin usarse. Tienes dos opciones.

Una opcion es llamar a la funcion de inmediato

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        });
                $(function() {
                        $( "#abrir" ).on( "click", function() {


                            function toggleVisibility() {
                            $('.ic3').toggleclass('hidden');
                            $('.ic4').toggleclass('hidden');
                            $('.ic5').toggleclass('hidden');
                            $('.ic6').toggleclass('hidden');
                            $('.ic7').toggleclass('hidden');
                            }

                            toogleVisibility();
                        });
                    });
```

O bien, no usar funciones

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        });
                $(function() {
                        $( "#abrir" ).on( "click", function() {

                            $('.ic3').toggleclass('hidden');
                            $('.ic4').toggleclass('hidden');
                            $('.ic5').toggleclass('hidden');
                            $('.ic6').toggleclass('hidden');
                            $('.ic7').toggleclass('hidden');

                        });
                    });
```

Comment: muchas gracias alanfcm me ha servido pero ahora tengo un problema el boton esta a lado derecho y cuando le doy a ocultar el boton se va hacia la derecha y queda pegado al ic1 ic2 y quiero que esa infomacion y el boton queden en linea.gracias seria buena ayuda.

Comment: @delfordiazdavila si tienes otro problema, puedes crear otra pregunta, eso sera lo mejor.

Comment: gracias kenny estoy creando otra pregunta solo que tengo que esperar 40 minutos de todas maneras gracias me ha servido mucho.